# Android, how to use phone's SQLite from C++?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've developed a [SQLite wrapper for React Native using C++](https://github.com/ospfranco/react-native-quick-sqlite). The easiest way to get it working was to include the SQLite amalgamation in the sources. This however increases the bundle size significantly. So I want to give the users the option to use the phone's embedded SQLite version.

[The iOS version is working](https://github.com/ospfranco/react-native-quick-sqlite/pull/53) (I exclude the sources if an environment flag is present). Android seems a lot more complicated though. Most of the answers I find on google recommend using the amalgamation path. It seems however it is possible to use the phone's SQLite version (it comes by default with the NDK).

I'm currently compiling the [amalgamation via CMake](https://github.com/ospfranco/react-native-quick-sqlite/blob/main/android/CMakeLists.txt).

I'm an Android noobie, would someone explain it like I'm 5 how can I link/access the SQLite headers from my NDK C++ code? Maybe I should just leave the `sqlite.h` header file and it will link with the phone's version?

EDIT 1: It seems leaving the header file only, does not work. I've also ran into this [Hacker News thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13498611). Some of the comments seem to suggest it is not really possible to access things like curl/sqlite/etc from the NDK code. Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot!

Edit 2: I found a link that might work https://blog.katastros.com/a?ID=00200-fd6cd935-b779-4f44-9b4c-efad582167e1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fumbling around I've come to the conclusion there is no way to achieve linking the phones sqlite via c++. It is also probably best so, old android versions have outdated versions, vendors also modify the running sqlite versions and they are full of old bugs and broken stuff.